# Proxy error with React/Express but only intermittently

Tags: reactjs, api, express, proxy, redux-thunk

I have an Express API that I'm sending requests to from a React front end.

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.set({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });
  Todo.find({}).then(todos => res.json({ todos }));
});
```

I have a proxy call in my package.json on the client side:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

From the front end action I'm sending a request to the API

```
export const getTodos = () => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios
      .get("/api/crudify")
      .then(res =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_TODOS,
          payload: res.data.todos
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

Everything seems to work fine, but randomly my console will give me a Proxy error, which causes the server to respond with a 500

[image: Proxy Error]

If I save and refresh the error goes away, than comes back a short time later. Anybody have any insight on this one?

Comment: If your Express server is behind the proxy, you don't need the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Don't you want the Express route to be `router.get("/crudify", ... );`?

Comment: I set the route location on the app side (outside of the express router) 'app.use("/api/crudify", todos);', I will try removing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, thanks

Comment: Just an update, removing the header didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having was nodemon was refreshing the node server and it was having a conflict with the front end React app, so adding --ignore frontend/ in my package.json seems to have fixed it.

`"server": "nodemon server --ignore frontend"`